# Set Value of a TextArea inside a WebBrowser Control (C# )

Tags: browser, textarea, set

```
textarea dir="ltr" tabindex="-1" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich text editor, vB_Editor_001_editor, press ALT 0 for help." class="cke_source cke_enable_context_menu" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; resize: none; outline: none; text-align: left;
```

This is the textarea. I want to send value there but. There isnt name or id. I couldnt send value.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebBrowser HtmlDocument [GetElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx) function

```
var elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");
foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
     if (element.InnerHTML.Contains("Rich text editor"))
     {
          // do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible simply to set the id, and then give it a *runat="server"* attribute, or is something stopping you from doing this?

**Markup:**

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" runat="server" tabindex="-1" role="textbox" 
aria-label="Rich text editor, vB_Editor_001_editor, press ALT 0 for help."
class="cke_source cke_enable_context_menu" 
style="width: 100%; height: 100%; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; resize: none; outline: none; text-align: left;">
```

**C# code:**

```
myTextArea.Value = "This is the inner value";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string textUWantToInput = "Inputed text";
var input = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");
input[0].SetAttribute("value", textUWantToInput);
```